# Updating scope inside of directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I think my problem will be related to $scope.$apply but I am not sure where to put it. It's also possible its related to just a poor understanding of a generic concept. Any clarity would be greatly appreciated.

A couple of key points, I'm using a browserify worflow so I am exporting my directives, they are fully functional in the app.

I've got this following code:

```
exports.gestutGallery = function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            auto: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.galleryImages = [];
            $scope.totalImages = $scope.galleryImages.length-1;
            $scope.currentImageIndex = 0;
            // Ternary check to set previous image
            $scope.previousImageIndex =
                $scope.currentImageIndex - 1 >= 0 ? $scope.currentImageIndex - 1 : $scope.totalImages;
            // Ternary check to set next image
            $scope.nextImageIndex =
                $scope.currentImageIndex + 1 <= $scope.totalImages ? $scope.currentImageIndex + 1 : 0;

            //Function References
            this.addToImages = function(image, cb){
                $scope.galleryImages.push(image);
            };
            this.pushImage = function(image){
                console.log(image);
            };
            this.pushPreviousImage = function(){
                pushImage($scope.galleryImages[$scope.previousImageIndex])
            };
            this.pushNextImage = function(){
                pushImage($scope.galleryImages[$scope.nextImageIndex])
            };
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.totalImages);
        }

    };
};

exports.gestutGalleryNavigation = function() {
    return {
        scope:true,
        require: "^gestutGallery",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, gsGlCtrl) {
            var navElements = elem.children();
            for(var i=0; i<navElements.length; i++){
                gsGlCtrl.addToImages(navElements[i].getAttribute('data-full-size-image'));
            };
        }

    }
};
```

I would like to be able to update the values of  `totalImages, previousImageIndex, nextImageIndex` etc after I've inserted the images from my dom into the images array. But it doesn't work. Where/how would I update those values? I've tried working with $observe with no luck and i've tried calling $scope.$apply() after the loop but always get an error that the digest is already in process.

Thanks for helping explain what I'm doing wrong.

### UPDATE:

So, after some further research, I've settled on nesting my $scope.value dependent numbers inside of a $watchCollection, like this:

```
        $scope.galleryImages = [];
        $scope.currentImageIndex = 0;

        $scope.$watchCollection('galleryImages', function() {

            $scope.totalImages = $scope.galleryImages.length-1;
            // Ternary check to set previous image
            $scope.previousImageIndex =
                $scope.currentImageIndex - 1 <= 0 ? $scope.totalImages : $scope.currentImageIndex - 1;
        // Ternary check to set next image
            $scope.nextImageIndex =
                $scope.currentImageIndex + 1 <= $scope.totalImages ? $scope.currentImageIndex + 1 : 0;

        });
```

I feel like this might be more expensive than I am wanting since I think that $watch function get's called on each image insert. However, it works and for the use case it's fast enough. I'll leave this open for the rest of the day to see if anyone can suggest a more elegant solution that's more "angular-y", otherwise I'll accept my own answer.

Comment: When, and where are you trying to inject images into the galleryImages array?
$scope.galleryImages = []; // ok, here you create your stack
$scope.totalImages = $scope.galleryImages.length-1; // But, what's that? You know the length, cause you just create your stack, it's, and it always be 0. Reducing 1 will cause total image to be equal to -1, is that really what you want?
In your methods, you are calling pushImage, without any context. I can be wrong, please tell me if I'm,  but you must call this.pushImage, and not only pushImage.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - the code gets a little trimmed in the viewport here, not sure if you saw below but there's a child directive following called "gestutGalleryNavigation" that pulls images from a data tag on a handful of encapsulated li's.

so, in this directive - I loop the li's, run the method from the parent directive to insert them into the array and THEN would like to update the other numbers since the true array.length would now be 2.

Comment: I think I see what you're doing, but can you create and add a jsfiddle please? It will be easiest to help you :-)

Comment: I've been stuck with something similar, so what I do is use $timeout to initiate a $scope.$apply after 300 milliseconds. Not great, but it works.

Comment: I think you should try to do not use isolated scope. In your last directive, just remove property scope=true, I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: You must use manual $scope.$apply when you are into an external callback that does not refer or use angular, like a gmap callback. To be able to apply changes into the $scope process, you should call $apply when done. In most of other case, manually call it is a bad solution, and must alert you on a sadly bad coded feature.

Comment: @Nico, the problem is that I actually need the isolated scope. It's a gallery feature which will be reused several different times on a page so I need to create unique values that are independent of each other. Otherwise that probably would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `$scope.totalImages`, `$scope.previousImageIndex` and `$scope.nextImageIndex` to functions:

```
$scope.totalImages = function(){ return $scope.galleryImages.length; };

// Ternary check to set previous image
$scope.previousImageIndex = function(){
  $scope.currentImageIndex - 1 >= 0 ? $scope.currentImageIndex - 1 : $scope.totalImages();
};

// Ternary check to set next image
$scope.nextImageIndex = function (){
  $scope.currentImageIndex + 1 <= $scope.totalImages() ? $scope.currentImageIndex + 1 : 0;
};
```

Comment: Forgive me if this is obvious, how does implementing them as functions help? Do they get re-run on each new $digest or something?

Comment: They will re-run if you will use this functions in binding expressions